# iOS, iPad- Multiple split view controllers with same master and detail view controllers

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uitabbar

I have tabbed application and 3 tabs contain exactly the same screens just with different data .

To implement functionality of those screens i used split view controller.
What i need to do is create 3 tabs that all use this split view controller(with the same master and detail view controllers) without duplicating master and detail view controllers three times in storyboard.

I tried creating three split view controllers and linking all of them to one master view controller and one detail view controller but that didn't work. Only one of those controllers actually used them. Other just showed black screen.

Any tips on how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it to work using the following:

In storyboard, Split View Controller's Storyboard ID is 'splitVc':

[image: Storyboard Layout]

Then, I used the following code in my `AppDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UISplitViewController *splitVc1 = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splitVc"];

    UISplitViewController *splitVc2 = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splitVc"];

    UISplitViewController *splitVc3 = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"splitVc"];

    UITabBarController *tabBarVc    = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    tabBarVc.viewControllers        = @[splitVc1, splitVc2, splitVc3];
    return YES;
}
```

This gave me what appeared to be 3 separate instances of the `UISplitViewController`, each assigned to 1 of 3 tabs in the `UITabBarController`, which is the root view controller for my `UIWindow`.

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Do you not get a warning/error in console when you do this? I don't really use Storyboards but when using a UISplitViewController it has to be the rootViewController, according to Apple: "A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create. In other words, you must always install the view from aUISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s window. The panes of your split-view interface may then contain navigation controllers, tab bar controllers, or any other type of view controller you need to implement your interface."

Comment: This configuration may not pass the HIG, but I get no compiler/console warnings in Xcode. I give no guarantee that Apple will approve of this! ;-)

Comment: It does exactly what i want but now i got another interesting problem. Value of "tabBarController.selectedIndex" is inconsistent with selected tab. That means for example i select first tab and selectedIndex=1. Then i select another tab and reselect first tab. Selected index is now 3. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I solved it by comparing title of tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem

Comment: How/when are you checking your `selectedIndex` and `selectedItem` values?

Comment: @mbm29414 ,you say apple will not approved it ,M creating app with multiple split view so does ur app get approved ?